# Is there a way to check if the HttpResponse is a redirect or not in a Spring interceptor?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

I would like to write a Spring MVC HandlerInterceptorAdaptor which does different things in the postHandle() method based on wether the HttpResponse is a redirect or not.

Is this possible, and if so how?

```
public class MenuInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
public final void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response,
                       Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws SystemException {
    if (redirect) {
        // do somethnig
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Is there a better way than this:

```
if (modelAndView.getView() instanceof RedirectView || modelAndView.getViewName().startsWith("redirect:")) {
    // Do something
 } else {
    // Do something else
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring MVC, a controller typically sends a redirect by returning a `View` that is a `RedirectView` or a String viewName that starts with the `redirect:` prefix. You can easily check for either of these.

Comment: Yes, but only by checking for type of the view, and viewName.startsWith. I was hoping for better way.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what kind of "interceptor" do you mean, and/or what kind of "HttpResponse"? If your HttpResponse has a "status code" or "response code", you just need to check that for a redirect code. Usually, 301 is used for redirects.

Comment: Guess I need to clarify my question. As stated in the body of the question a Spring Interceptor. I will edit with some sample code.